Manufacturer responsible to make sure valid after market is available when discontinuing eom?
When a manufacturer discontinues an oem part that is integral to the operation of a vehicle, is it their responsibility to ensure that aftermarket parts are available and compatible via third parties?
i.e. axles, oem not available, aftermarket not compatible, renders vehicle useless. outside of warranty. years 2015-2023.  Side note, insurance companies are not obligated to cover policy if used parts are the cause of the accident.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Wasn't this asked recently here or on Law SE? Why would a used axle be the cause of an accident, any more than the already failed one? It may well be an OEM part anyway. In UK, a deviation from the small print insurance requirements must be a material contributory factor, not a weasel's get-out clause.

It was asked on Skeptics SE.

Yeah, I messed up and asked in the wrong forum and it got shut down.  Totally understandable, It was suggested that I come here, and I was provided a link.

Any axle can be the cause of an accident.  I blew an axle in AZ at 70 mph and almost had a head on.  But my point on the used part is if it is used and it causes damage to person or property, ins co have the right not to cover.

I can answer for the US here in stating that manufacturers are required to have available OEM parts for five years after manufacture of a vehicle. There is no requirement for the OEM manufacturer to ensure aftermarket parts are available. Something to note is, manufacturers will use the same parts across several lines of vehicles for several years. When doing so, this means they'll have the parts for five years after the last vehicle uses it.
The only way an aftermarket part becomes available is if there is a call for them (ie: people want to buy the replacement parts). If it is lucrative enough for them to make/produce/procure the replacement parts, they'll do it. If they aren't going to make money at it, then they won't. In the case of when a part is no longer available through the OEM or aftermarket, the next best thing is a parts car, usually pulling parts from one at a junkyard.
I don't know about outside of the US, but I would assume it is something similar.

And often many Ford parts aren't made by Ford to begin with, so the decision to keep making them comes from the original parts supplier (and their contract with Ford). Ford used as an example only, not specific to Ford...

@JonCuster - You're right about that as well.

Aftermarket axles for my specific car do not work.  Oem discontinued rear, front axles, output shaft and pressure sensors. Hundreds of comments over this, reasons cited e.g. splining is wrong, too short, manufactured much weaker, less grease.  Oem was not available anywhere. I went through 3 axles in less than 30 days & total between damages, repair, transportation, hauling etc I lost over 11k.  The manufacturer and corporate office said see ya, take a hike.  This was for a 2016 Jeep.  I am truly blown away that a vehicle can be allowed to stay on the road with no sufficient repair available.
